# Corrupted drive and can’t boot after Windows 10 update

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, command-line, boot, filesystem-corruption

I have (had) 2 computers (Lenovo laptop, dell tower) running windows 10. Although normally they sleep, this last week they were both rebooted.  When they tried to load windows, they failed to load and instead entered the “Automatic Repair Cycle”.

On my laptop I was able to repair my machine by resetting my apps and windows but keeping my files in tact. This was not the case with the dell.

Automatic Repair:

> Automatic Repair couldn’t repair your PC...
>   Log file: C:\WINDOWS\System32\Logfiles\Srt\SrtTrail.txt

Going into Advanced Options>Troubleshoot
I can either **Reset this PC** or **Advanced options**.

Resetting my PC and trying to keep my files yields “There was a problem resetting your PC. No changes were made.” A similar message comes when trying to reset the PC without keeping files.

Going into Advanced options I see:

1. **Startup Repair** (gives same error and logfile name)
2. **System Restore** (No restore points created
3. **System Image Recovery** (Waiting to see if I have a better option)
4. **Command Prompt**
5. **UEFI Firmware Settings** (No idea what that is)
6. **Startup Settings**

At a minimum, I want to be able to copy my data from my D drive to an external drive. So I went to the command line. 
When I type `d:` to get to it, I get the message:

> The volume does not contain a recognizable file system. Make sure that all required file system drivers are loaded and that the volume is not corrupted.

I then ran `chkdsk d:` :

> They type of the file system is UDF. Cannot read Anchor Volume Descriptor Pointer. Chkdsk aborted.

This made me sad. I also don’t have internet on the machine so any new software will have to be loaded via usb.

How can I get my data from my D drive?

Comment: You're trying to access your CD Drive. Try `C:`.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a bad Intel patch intended to mitigate the Meltdown bug included in the Jan 2017 Cumulative update from MS. You will need to Re-image or do a system restore to Dec 2017 in order to recover. You need to install the Feb 2018 Cumulative update from MS before rebooting again. If you have no restore points and want to recover, you can install win10 on another hard drive and connect the non-booting drive as a secondary drive to recover your files.  Had this issue with about 10 machines, fortunately I did an image backup on all of them weekly with Veeam Backup.  To just recover your files, you can put the drive in another computer as a secondary drive and it should be readable.